# How to install Gnome 3 in Linux Mint 18.1 (Serena)?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome3

I looked around for a while, found some instructions for LM 17 which, according to comments, don't work for LM 18. Gnome appears in Synaptic, but I'm not sure if it's as simple as that (and I obviously don't want to break my system).

So, how to install Gnome 3 in Linux Mint?

A derivative question: does it matter whether I start with Mint Cinnamon, XFCE, or MATE? If so, which should I start with, in order to transition to Gnome?

Answer (score -1):

I've tried installing it on linux mint 18, however it failed to load gdm. You may not get the same results as I but I would still suggest using another display manager. Also, I would suggest starting out with mate or xfce as I have heard that if you install it alongside cinnamon it may crash.